# I want to show $E(B(t)-B(s))^4=3(t-s)^2$

Tags: self-study, expected-value, stochastic-processes

Let $B(t)$ and $B(s)$ are  brownian-motion I want to show $$E(B(t)-B(s))^4=3(t-s)^2$$

thanks for help.

Comment: assuming s < t?

Comment: @BCLC There's no need to assume  $t>s$ in the question. However, it can be assumed for convenience in an answer without loss of generality

Comment: @Glen_b because of the even powers?

Comment: @BCLC Yes, plainly. $E[(-X)^4] = E[X^4]$ and $(-a)^2 = a^2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $B(t)$, $t\ge 0$ is a Brownian motion, then $B(t)-B(s)$ has $N(0,t-s)$ distribution. From there, you just need to figure out how to compute the 4th moment of a Gaussian with given variance, which I trust you can do.

Comment: assuming s < t?